# Как открыть приложение из фона по комбинации клавиш?

Tags: java, app, hide, многопоточность, swing

Интересует вопрос, как в `java` реализовать открытие фонового приложения по комбинации клавиш. Ну или ещё это можно назвать как "горячие клавиши". Весь процесс можно не расписывать, как запучтить поток в фоне и прочее уже умеем, а вот как событие отследить? Дайте ответ или ссылку на мануал, можно на английском. Спасибо.

P.S. Визуализация на `Swing`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Вот](http://habrahabr.ru/post/124567/)

Comment: Вполне подходит, спасибо.